# How to prove that $x=\frac{p_n+p_{n-1}x_{n+1}}{p_n+p_{n-1}x_{n+1}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions, ergodic-theory, continued-fractions

We know that \begin{equation*}
a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{a_3+\cfrac{1}{\ddots+\cfrac{1}{a_n}}}}}=[a_0,a_1, \cdots, a_n]
\end{equation*}

If $\frac{p_n}{q_n}=[a_0,a_1, \cdots, a_n]$.

Let us define $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{p_n}{q_n}=x$$

> How to prove that $$x=\frac{p_n+p_{n-1}x_{n+1}}{p_n+p_{n-1}x_{n+1}}$$ where $x_n=[a_n,a_{n+1},\cdots]$

Yes, there is a misprint  [here 2nd page last equation](https://math.colorado.edu/~rohi1040/expository/ergodicthysimplecontfracs.pdf). Can anyone rectify it and prove it.

Comment: I think there's a misprint: that says $x=1$.

Comment: Which one sir ?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Along the way in a proof of a recent answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2715374/how-to-interpret-left-beginsmallmatrixp-n-p-n-1-q-n-q-n-1-endsma/2715411 you get $a_0 + \frac{1}{\ddots + \frac{1}{a_n + \frac{1}{x}}} = \frac{p_n x + p_{n-1}} {q_n x + q_{n-1}}$.

Comment: I recommend Khinchin, now a very inexpensive paperback. http://store.doverpublications.com/0486696308.html He does all the measure theory: he invented it.

Comment: There we go, your question is formula (16), page 8. This is before he has required the $a_i$ be positive integers, so Theorem 7 on page 8 says "if it converges" and on page 10 he gives a condition for convergence that includes positive integers as a special case.

Comment: or http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Continued%20Fractions%20Khinchin.pdf

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think you are saying that the corrected equation would be $x=\frac{p_n+p_{n-1}x_{n+1}}{q_n+q_{n-1}x_{n+1}}$ where $x_n=[a_n,a_{n+1},\cdots]$, now could you please prove it from the link you have given to me. As I am not geeting from that too.

Comment: I also recommend Khinchin; I found chapter 1 to be great.  Khinchin is now free, online, at http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Continued%20Fractions%20Khinchin.pdf